# How to change the colour (color) of sencha chart column

Tags: extjs, charts, sencha-touch

Morning

I am using the code below to create a chart in Sencha

It works fine, however, all the columns are different random colours. I need then all to be the same colour.

I tried using `fill: 'blue'` and `fill: '#000080'` and `style: { fill: 'blue' }`  in series in but that did not

```
var days30fields = new Array('name');
var days30fieldsd = new Array();
var days30fieldValues = new Object();
days30fieldValues['name'] = 'Last 30 days';
for(var xd = 1; xd<31; xd++){
    days30fields.push('day'+xd);
    days30fieldsd.push('day'+xd);
    days30fieldValues['day'+xd] = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
}

var chartb = new Ext.chart.Chart({
          renderTo : Ext.getBody(), 
          xtype: 'chart',
          itemId:'demochart',
          title: 'Sales Figures',
          animate: true,
            width : '80%',
            height : '70%',
            margin: '150 auto',
            store: {
                fields: days30fields,
                data:
                    //'name': 'Last 30 Days',
                    /*'day1': 10,
                    'day2': 12,
                    'day3': 14,
                    'day4': 8,
                    'day5': 13*/
                    days30fieldValues

            },
            axes: [{
                type: 'numeric',
                position: 'left',
                minimum: 0,
                renderer: function (value) {
                    value = value / 1000000;
                    return value.toFixed(1);
                },
                title:  'Number of orders',
                fields: days30fieldsd
            }, {
                type: 'category',
                position: 'bottom',
                title: 'Days',
                fields: 'name',

            }],
            series: [{
                highlight: true,
                type: 'column',
                stacked: true,
                xField: 'name',
                yField: days30fieldsd,

            }]
        });
```

And in the view config:

```
items: [
    {
                xtype : 'container',
                flex: 1,
                items: [chartb]  
          },
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://tinyurl.com/lets-fiddle)

Comment: did you tried exactly like "  style: { fill: 'blue' } " in series

Comment: Yes, tried style: { fill: 'blue' } and that didn't work either

Comment: can i see the screen shot ?

Comment: Fiddle: http://tinyurl.com/lets-fiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

**Solution 1**

```
series: [{
    highlight: true,
    type: 'column',           
    //stacked: true,
    xField: 'name',
    yField: days30fieldsd,
    renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store){
       return Ext.apply(attr, {
          fill: 'red'
       });
    }
}]
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MXSXs/7/) fiddle

---

**Solution 2** (usefull for applying multiple colours)

Create New theme using `Ext.chart.theme.Base` for your chart and apply that.

```
Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.ColumnTheme', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.theme.Base',
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent([Ext.apply({ 

           colors: ['red','green']

        }, config)]);
    }
});
```

Apply `ColumnTheme` using theme config in your chart

```
    var chartb = new Ext.chart.Chart({
             renderTo : Ext.getBody(), 
             theme:'ColumnTheme',    
              xtype: 'chart',
              itemId:'demochart',
               .... same code
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXSXs/8/)

Comment: Thanks. That's giving mean error Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null. I have traced it to Ext.chart.theme.ColumnTheme.  In my app.js I already have requires: [Ext.chart.theme.Base, other stuff...

Comment: @JezD i updated my answer.. just follow solution 1 and ignore solution 2

Comment: It doesn't work if you have a renderer for the label